# SSRS: Calculated value on Y-axis

Tags: reporting-services, charts, axis

In our production environment, I have a big list with 1 record (the machine's status) per machine per timestamp. This list is populated every 10 seconds so every 10 seconds I know which machine is in which status. I have made a bar chart of this data which counts how much records there are per machine per status to get an overview of the performance of our machines:

[image: Example chart:]

As a consequence of this approach, the Y-axis shows how much records are present. We already know there is always 1 record per 10 seconds and I would like to have the Y-axis showing the hours. Instead of eg 1500 would like to see on the Y-axis: 1500 * 10 (sec) / 3600 (= 4,2 hours)

Does anybody know how this is possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use that formula in the Series expression, together with a Numeric format for the Axis Label to show the decimal place.